# Registration and log in through public key cryptography?

Tags: public-key, passwords

I read about zero knowledge proofs.

Let's say you want to create an account at a website. You choose a password $p$ and from $p$ you derive deterministically a public & private key pair $(e,d)$ and send $e$ to the server. Every time you want to log in, you and the server play a game: The server sends you an encrypted message containing a random number, and you decrypt it and send it back; this proves you have knowledge of the private key and the password without revealing either. Is such a scheme used?

Comment: Alright @MaartenBodewes, you win. I have deleted my flawed answer. Now I am curious, so please provide a better answer to this question. After all the time we've wasted in comments, surely you can whip up something.

Comment: In my proposal, upon login and registration the client generates the public-private key pair deterministically from the password (this has to be through a one-way function). If he's logging in, he sets up a private session with the server and says that he is user $x$, then the server encrypts a message using the private key it's stored for $x$ and he responds by sending back the decrypted plaintext. If he's registering, he sends the public key and username to the server which stores both. This is different from using just a secret key because a password is memorable. The server never learns...

Comment: ...the password.